# HQL Join not working

Tags: sql, hibernate, join, hql

I got a problem with a quiet simple join statement.

There is a table A and another table B. Table A has an `idNumber`.
Table B has got an `number`.
Now I want to join this tables on `idNumber=number`

What I do is:-

```
A.executeQuery("Select a from A a inner JOIN B b ON a.idNumber=b.number")
```

Unfortunately, I get an empty list as result but that is wrong. 
Anyone has an idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are running a sql query. So for running sql query, you need to define which columns you are selecting.

```
A.executeQuery("Select a.* from A a inner JOIN B b ON a.idNumber=b.number") // don't forget * after a
```

PS. For hql query I need to know your class structure. 
  Hibernate Query Language (HQL) is an object-oriented query language, similar to SQL, but instead of operating on tables and columns, HQL works with persistent objects and their properties. 
Let's assume class A has an instance of B. Then JOIN query will be as following.

```
Select a from A a inner JOIN a.B
```

Answer (score 0):

A has an instance of B. B is in the package a.package.name
I just tried

```
A.executeQuery("Select a from A a inner JOIN a.package.name.B b where a.idNumber=b.number")
```

Comment: select a from Event a, package.name.B b where b.number = a.idNumber
Returns an empty list. Size should be one.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem was that one Table was in an extern Plugin and it was not possible to join them here. I had to do two requests.